# how can i expand or double click TreeItem without RDP with pywinauto

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I trying expand or double_click() tree item.
This code works just fine when rdp is open with mouse cursor and double_click_input(), but not working, when rdp closed because there isn't mouse cursor.

I trying methods click(), or double_click(), they not working.

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title='myApplication')
dlg = app.window(title='Control Panel of myApplication')

#this click() works without rdp
dlg.child_window(auto_id="MainPanelForm.gridLayoutWidget.MainPanelWidget.rightFrame.setupWidget.setupButton").click()
dlg.child_window(title="Система", control_type="TreeItem").double_click_input()
```

[inspect.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMOlv.jpg)
[inspect.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34ftj.jpg)

If I try `dlg.child_window(title="Система", control_type="TreeItem").print_control_identifiers()`

```
TreeItem - 'Система'    (L3102, T196, R3877, B220)
['СистемаTreeItem', 'Система', 'TreeItem']
child_window(title="Система", control_type="TreeItem")
```

How can I do this with pywinauto or it's impossible and I need to try it another way?

The are methods i get:

```
Pattern object attributes: ['AddRef', 'GetCachedColumnHeaderItems',
'GetCachedRowHeaderItems', 'GetCurrentColumnHeaderItems',
'GetCurrentRowHeaderItems', 'QueryInterface', 'Release', '_AddRef',
'_IUIAutomationTableItemPattern__com_GetCachedColumnHeaderItems',
'_IUIAutomationTableItemPattern__com_GetCachedRowHeaderItems',
'_IUIAutomationTableItemPattern__com_GetCurrentColumnHeaderItems',
'_IUIAutomationTableItemPattern__com_GetCurrentRowHeaderItems',
'_IUnknown__com_AddRef', '_IUnknown__com_QueryInterface',
'_IUnknown__com_Release', '_QueryInterface', '_Release', '__bool__',
'__class__', '__cmp__', '__com_interface__', '__ctypes_from_outparam__',
'__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__',
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__',
'__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__',
'__map_case__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__',
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__',
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_b_base_',
'_b_needsfree_', '_case_insensitive_', '_compointer_base__get_value',
'_idlflags_', '_iid_', '_methods_', '_needs_com_addref_', '_objects',
'_type_', 'from_param', 'value']
```

Comment: main_window.YourTreeItem.click_input(button='left', double=True)
In general, things that don't implement click() just use click_input().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All known recipes for remote execution are collected in the [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html).

Probably you should customize RDP settings to allow minimizing/disconnection without losing active desktop.

---

Below I describe less reliable methods which may not work for some apps like Qt5.

Also for TreeItem it's worth trying method `.select()` which should use SelectionItem pattern. This pattern availability cab be checked in Inspect.exe. See the screenshot:

[image]

Also it's possible to try available patterns by menu "Action".

P.S. For your case the available pattern is `TableItem` which is accessible by property (not method!) `.iface_table_item`. Just list all available methods for this pattern by built-in function `dir()`:

```
attrs = dir(dlg.child_window(title="Система", control_type="TreeItem").iface_table_item)
print("Pattern object attributes: {}".format(attrs))
```

The pattern object comes from `UIAutomationCore.dll` as a COM object. We don't use it anywhere in pywinauto yet, but it can be used and inspected as any normal Python object.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i dont get, how i can use these methods for my purpose. I listed them in my question.

Comment: Hmm... good question. Let me download SecurOS Lite and try to inspect it.

Comment: Well, I've played with PyQt application that implements similar QTreeView, but it seems the Qt5 implementation is empty from UI automation point of view. Calling any action from Inspect.exe doesn't take any effect. So you have to use `click_input()` and related methods with proper RDP customization. Sorry, no luck. P.S. TableItem pattern is useless because it's for some read-only properties.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, SecurOS has its own API for VBScript, so it's most probably IDispatch COM objects or custom COM objects that can be used in Python by `win32com.client` or `comtypes.client` modules. Maybe this object model is more useful and functional. In the API guide they provide GUI interface for VBScript, but I think it's possible to create `Core` object using above Python modules.